# Stuck trying to align menu items next to logo

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am having trouble getting my menu items to align next to my logo, within my navbar. My menu items are appearing just below my logo and to the right, the horizontal position is correct, I need to adjust the vertical position up so that the items are in line and within the navigation bar.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Serving Grace - Home</title>
  <!-- Stylesheet -->
  <link href="Private/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="Logo/logo.png"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Volunteer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
      <ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="image">
    <img src="Images/Content.png"/>
  </div>

  <div id="info">
    <img src="Images/info.png"/>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="Images/Facebook.fw.png"></a>
    <a href="www.twitter.com"><img src="Images/Twitter.fw.png"></a>
    <a href="www.google.com"><img src="Images/Google.fw.png"></a>

    <p id="copyright">&#169; 2013 Jeffery Evans</p>
  </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
}

#content {
    width: 1090px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 5px 3px 5px #888;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#nav {
    background-color: #222222;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#nav li {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 25px 20px 10px 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #F59239;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F59239;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#logo {
    padding-right: 300px;
    position: inline-block;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: #222222;
}

#image {
    top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 15px;
}

#info {
    top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 30px;
}

#footer {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1090px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #222222;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#footer a {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#copyright {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
#nav {
    height: 100px;
}
```

try something like

```
#nav {
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

if that doesn't work, then also try using line-height for your nav li and/or nav a

THE EASIEST WAY would be to do something just like this

```
#logo {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

That will just push the logo down by 10px , adjust accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried changing to "line-height" and adjusting that, but it made my navbar way to wide. Also, I had the same idea about adjusting padding, but when I do it, it doesn't change anything. I'm not sure, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the logo.png is very wide, it may be pushing the menu items to the next line. I tried your code a with small gif for the logo and it worked fine (image and menu text were aligned at bottom) in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I hadn't really thought about that, I just tried resizing the logo but had no luck. Menu items still fell below the colored navbar. The logo is 280px x 110px.